# Aura Component Date Validation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, experience-cloud

Hi I am working with community portal which collects data by using custom form aura component.
I would like to set a validation rule of minimum age 18 on "Date of Birth" field which is a date picker. after entering the date in input field , users must see the an error if the age is less than 18 before submitting the form.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" 
                access="global">
     <aura:attribute name="FirstName" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="LastName" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="DOB" type="Date" default="" />
     <aura:attribute name="isDOBValid" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <br/><br/>
     <lightning:input label="First Name" name="studentfirstname" value="{!v.FirstName}" />
    <br/>
    <lightning:input label="Last Name" name="studentlastname" value="{!v.LastName}" />
    <br/>
    <lightning:input label="DOB" name="date" type="date" value="{!v.DOB}" onchange="{!c.validateDOB}" messageWhenRangeUnderflow="DOB should be at least 18 years ago" required="true"/>
     <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isDOBValid}">
        <div style="color: red;">DOB should be at least 18 years ago</div>
    </aura:if>
    <br/>
     <lightning:button label="Submit"></lightning:button>
</aura:component>
```

Please guide me on how this can be achieved.?

Also this DOB is associated to an abject and field in salesforce to create a record. wondering if I give a validation rule on DOB in salesforce, will that be enforced on portal form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your provided cmp code, I have written the js code for the DOB validation. In the Js function, I have to get the date selected in the form and then find the age to check if the age is less than 18 or not. Based on that I have set the isDOBValid attribute value to show and hide the validation message. Also, the attribute isDOBValid default value is set to be true in cmp file.

DOBValidateForm.cmp:

```
    <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" 
                access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="FirstName" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="LastName" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="DOB" type="Date" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="isDOBValid" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <br/><br/>
    <lightning:input label="First Name" name="studentfirstname" value="{!v.FirstName}" />
    <br/>
    <lightning:input label="Last Name" name="studentlastname" value="{!v.LastName}" />
    <br/>
    <lightning:input label="DOB" name="date" type="date" value="{!v.DOB}" onchange="{!c.validateDOB}" messageWhenRangeUnderflow="DOB should be at least 18 years ago" required="true"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isDOBValid}">
        <div style="color: red;">DOB should be at least 18 years ago</div>
    </aura:if>
    <br/>
    <lightning:button label="Submit"></lightning:button>
</aura:component>
```

DOBValidateForm.js:

```
({
    validateDOB : function(component, event, helper) {
        var dob = event.getSource().get('v.value');        
        console.log('dob : ' + dob);        
        const date1 = Number(dob.substring(0, 4));
        alert(date1);
        const date2 = new Date();
        var year = date2.getFullYear();
        
        var Age = year-date1;
        alert(Age);        
        
        if(Age < 18){
            component.set("v.isDOBValid",true);    
        } else if(Age > 18){
            component.set("v.isDOBValid",false);    
        }        
    }
})
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Hi Tushar, and welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [answer], then **[edit]** your post to add some explanation of what you changed and how it helped solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much the js helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ui:inputDate`, it is long since deprecated. Instead, use `lightning-input type="date"`, and to enforce this in the UI, use `min="YYYY-MM-DD"`, where that date would be calculated in the controller to be 18 years ago.

Also, yes, if you're using `lightning-record-edit-form` or the like, it'll be validated on save and shown in the UI. If you create your own form, a validation rule would still prevent saving, but you'll have to handle the error yourself.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. I will try this out. Also can you please advice on how to get calculate in the controller.